# jquery - adding query parameter to a url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new with jquery, I have a button on an html page, I want jquery to click it adding a parameter to it.
I know that to click I can do :

```
$("#myButton").click();
```

but I don't know how to add a parameter to the url.
Thank you!

Comment: `"I want jquery to click it adding a parameter to it."` - That's not really clear.  What are you actually trying to accomplish, and how is "adding a parameter to the URL" going to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by manipulating `window.location.search`

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){
     window.location.search += '&foo=bar';
});
```